# How Music player work when we kill (swipe) the recent app

Tags: android

When I play the music and come on home the music is running, but when I kill the app music is restart. I want to run the music when I kill the app instead of it restarting.
Please help me.
My code is:----
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Context context;
private Button mPlay, mStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myservice.class);
            startService(service);
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent name = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myservice.class);
            stopService(name);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And my service class is:---

```
public class Myservice extends Service implements
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{

private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder(); 
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private int length = 0;

    public Myservice() { } 

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        Myservice getService()
         {
            return Myservice.this;
         }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){return mBinder;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate (){
      super.onCreate(); 

       mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.follow);
       mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

       if(mPlayer!= null)
        {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        }


        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

      public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int       
          extra){

            onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
            return true;
        }
          });
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)

    {
         mPlayer.start();
         return START_STICKY;

    }

    public void pauseMusic()
    {
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length=mPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); 

        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic()
    {
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()==false)
        {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic()
    {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy ()

    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mPlayer != null)
        {
        try{
         /*mPlayer.stop();
         mPlayer.release();*/
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ondestroy", 2000).show();
            }finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        if(mPlayer != null)
        {
            try{
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            }finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Make your service as foreground when you start music by calling startForeground(notification_id,notification)

Comment: @SaiKiran How would that solve the problem?

Comment: @XaverKapeller, refer to my answer, I will update more description.

Comment: @SaiKiran No,  I am asking you because it doesn't work. If the process is killed the `Service` is killed as well, no matter of its a foreground `Service` or not. That is not the solution, why are you suggesting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below method in your service and call the method when media starts playing. Foreground service are high priority service which are not killed by android system often, starting a foreground service needs a notification. you can manually stop foreground service by calling `stopForeground(true)`. Please watch for basics of Media Playback [State of Media Playback (Android Dev Summit 2015)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6pFai3ll9E)

```
private static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = 91;

    private void runAsForeground(){ 
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                    .setContentText("Media is playing")
                                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
```